# Show that Function f(x,y)=|xy| is differentiable at 0 ,but is not of class C1 in any in any neighborhood of 0？

Tags: calculus, analysis

Munkers's analysis on manifold Section6 Ex1:
Show that Function $f(x,y)=|xy|$ is differentiable at 0 ,but is not of class $C^1$ in any in any neighborhood of $0$ .

To show it is differentiable is easy , then I get ${\partial f}/{\partial x} = y^2x/|xy|$, but I fail to see it is discontinous at $0$. ${\partial f}/{\partial x} = y^2x/|xy|=|y|^2x/|x||y|=|y|x/|x|= y*sgn(x)$ which is $0$ when $y$ tend to $0$.

Comment: Please review [our page on how to ask good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). This question needs serious revision, at the least (e.g. including the full problem and any context about your attempts/specific confusions).

Answer (score 2):

You've overlooked an aspect of the question: you're focusing on whether $f$ is $C^1$ *at* $0$, but the question is whether $C^1$ is continuous on an *entire neighborhoods* of $0$.

> In particular, every neighborhood of $0$ contains a point where $y \neq 0$.
>
>  Can $\partial f / \partial x$ be $C^1$ at such a point?

Aside: note that both derivatives need to be continuous, not just one of them. It's unclear if you knew that and were being concise, or if you overlooked that.

Comment: Why is $f$ differentiable at zero? That's because we can take $B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and this meets the definition? That is, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)-Bh}{|h|}=0$? Well, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)-Bh}{|h|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(m,n)}{|h|}\lim_{(m,n)\to (0,0)}\frac{|mn|}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}$ and $\frac{|mn|}{\sqrt{m^2+n^2}}\leq |m|\to 0$? where $h:=(m,n)$

Comment: According to what you say, every neighborhood of zero contains a point $(x,y)$ that satisfies $y\neq 0$, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ would not be continuous since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{|x|}$ does not exist. I'm reasoning well?